# Percentage Scaling

Tags: percentages

I am looking at player win percentages for example:

```
Name        Race_Count       Win_Count       Win_Percentage
Player A    53               5               0.094 %
Player B    47               9               0.191 %
Player C    3                1               0.333 %
```

How do I evaluate (or scale) the win percentage in respect to how many races the player has competed in? For example Player C's win percentage is impressive but has only done three races compared to the other players who have done significantly more races.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Raymond

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that Player C's win percentage is unlikely to be a true reflection of his ability because of the small number of races he's participated in. And what you're asking for is a mathematical way of correcting for this effect. Is that right? I think the answer will depend on what you're using the data for, and it will probably require other data besides the number of wins and losses. For example, if players tend to perform very consistently, then one win out of three may be more meaningful than if performances vary a lot. Without further information, math won't be able..

Comment: to say much about this. Also, statisticians will probably know more about how to analyze data like this than will mathematicians.